# Style to submit buttons differently

Tags: html, css

I have a submit button that looks a particular way but I want a different looking submit button on a different page. I am struggling to figure out how to change the style for the second submit button.

The html looks like this for the first button:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
input[type="submit"],
button[type="submit"] {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 48px;
  border: 2px solid #47b475;
  background: #47b475;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;

}
```

I have tried creating something like:

```
.button2 {

/*bunch of code

}
```

but I try :

```
<button type="submit" class="button2">Submit</button>
```

And that doesn't work so I am obviously missing something. Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just run into a **CSS selector specificity problem**.
You need to repeat the `input[type="submit"]` before your class `.button2` to make it more specific and therefore override any lower specificity style

```css
input[type="submit"],
button[type="submit"] {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 48px;
  background: #47b475;
  border: 2px solid #47b475;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}


input[type="submit"].button2,
button[type="submit"].button2{

  background: #1CEA6E;
  border: 2px solid #1CEA6E;

}
```

```html
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<button type="submit" class="button2">Submit</button>
```